# Unclear what steps to take...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to simplify $$\frac{6^{\frac3{12}}} {3^{\frac 4{12}}}$$ which should be $$\frac {2^{\frac 14}}{3^{\frac 1{12}}}$$ But I fail to see what step to take to get there...
I thought we couldn't divide the $6$ and $3$ since they're different bases....

A little hint would be very welcome

Comment: $6^a = 2^a 3^a$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{6^{\frac{3}{12}}}{3^{\frac{4}{12}}} = \frac{6^{\frac{1}{4}}}{3{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

**Hint:**

From here, notice $$(ab)^n = a^nb^n$$

Applying it here, you get

$$6^{\frac{1}{4}} = (3\cdot 2)^{\frac{1}{4}} = 3^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot 2^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

Now, you can simplify.

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$\frac{6^{3/12}}{3^{4/12}}=\frac{2^{3/12}3^{3/12}}{3^{4/12}}=\frac{2^{3/12}}{3^{4/12-3/12}}=\frac{2^{1/4}}{3^{1/12}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Just break down into steps:
$$\frac{6^{\frac3{12}}} {3^{\frac 4{12}}}=\frac{6^{\frac1{4}}} {3^{\frac 1{3}}}$$
Use: $$6^n=2^n\cdot 3^n$$
$$=\frac{(3^{\frac 1{4}})\cdot (2^{\frac14})} {3^{\frac 1{3}}}$$
Now use: $$\frac{a^m}{a^n}=a^{m-n}=\frac1{a^{n-m}}$$
$$=\frac{2^{\frac14}}{3^{\frac13-\frac14}}$$

> $$=\frac{2^{\frac14}}{3^{\frac1{12}}}$$